# Java zip manipulation corrupts jarfiles

Tags: java, python, jar, zip

I am developing an application in Java which needs to patch files to a certain `.jar` file and then runs the jar.  I had written a previous version of this application in Python using the 'zipfile' library, which patched the jar and ran it successfully.  The Java application, however, creates a jarfile that is 'Invalid or corrupted' according to the runtime when I attempt to run the jar (using java.exe from the command line), even though 7-zip can open the jarfile just fine.  For reference, the Python zip code was as follows:

```
import os
import zipfile

def extractzipfile(filename, target):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r') as z:
        for name in z.namelist():
            if name.endswith("/"):
                continue
            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(target, name))):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(target, name)))
                except:
                    pass
            with open(os.path.join(target, name), "wb") as f:
                f.write(z.read(name))

def compresszipfile(directory, target):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w') as z:
        for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                z.write(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root.replace(directory, ""), file))
```

The jarfile was extracted with `extractzipfile`, patched, and recompressed with `compresszipfile`.  My new Java version of the application uses zip4j to handle zipping and unzipping.  The code in Java is as follows:

```
public static void decompressZipfile(String zipFile, String outputDir) throws ZipException {
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
    zip.extractAll(outputDir);
}

public static void compressZipfile(String sourceDir, String outputFile) throws ZipException {
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(outputFile);
    ZipParameters params = new ZipParameters();
    params.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
    params.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
    for (File f : new File(sourceDir).listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            zip.addFolder(f, params);
        } else {
            zip.addFile(f, params);
        }
    }
}
```

As before, the jarfile is extracted, patched, and recompressed using the above methods.

So my question is:  Does anyone have any ideas about why the Java application is generating a corrupt jarfile when the Python application is not?  Is there a difference between Python-created zipfiles and zip4j/Java zipfiles?

Also note:  The META-INF folder was not modified in any way in the Python application, and the jar ran just fine, so that should not be a factor in the issue.  Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Please let me know if I need to give further information about the issue.